# How can I install berkeley database for IOS device

Tags: ios, berkeley-db

Hi I want to install  berkeley db in my MAC. My Xcode version is 4.5.2. I downloaded db-5.3.21(Berkeley) from oracle site.I installed command line tool for xcode.
I installed berkeley db in my MAC for iPhoneSimulator. Where as for iPhone device I am unable to install.
I am following below link for installing the berkeley db.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/installation/build_unix_iphone.html

When I am installing berkeley db for IOS device it is showing following error.

`checking for arm-apple-darwin11.4.2-sh... no
checking for sh... /bin/sh
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for arm-apple-darwin11.4.2-cc... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in` `/Users/celstra/rajaramesh/db-5.3.21/build_unix':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables`
See `config.log' for more details`

...............................
The error is telling that C compiler cannot create executables... But for iPhonesimulator it is not showing the error...

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4644980/berkeley-db-for-iphone?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475227/how-can-i-use-the-berkeley-db-within-an-ios-application?rq=1

Comment: Hi maddy Thank you .I followed above link but still the problem Persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked config.log? It is possible that something went wrong during C compiler check, e.g. cannot find header files, ...